# Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 Can not Load mso.dll for designer view

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, memory, memory-management, dll

I am doing an ASP project and I am having the following problem when trying to switch from code to designer view .A pop up appears and visual studio shuts down.

```
cannot load "c:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\Common7\packages\vwd\mso.dll
```

here are some solution from the Internet that I tried and did not work out 
1. I reinstalled the software ( visual studio 10.0 )
2. Some suggest to user less privileged account, so I also tried that . Did not work .
3.I have Microsoft Office Installed and its working just fine
3. I read some vague thing about a certain patch ( but could not find it )
4. The mso.dll file is NOT missing or deleted .

Here is my installation folder for my visual studio 10.0

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
```

HELP ! ? !

Answer (score 0):

I know this post from long ago but if someone still have an issue:

Update PATH environment variables with below proper path:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\vwd.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I tried many solutions available on the web. The one that really worked for me was:

First, I used the utility "[Depency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)". I opened the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\vwd\mso.dll" file with this utility and it found missing Msvcr90.dll file dependency.

Then download the [Microsoft Visual C ++ 2008 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368) and run it.

The problem was solved.